# Nginx url rewrite in two folders

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

In Apache I have a .htaccess file in the root to rewrite URL's with an exception to a folder called admin. In the admin folder I have another .htaccess file to rewrite URL's in that folder.

How can I achieve the same using a nginx server block?

This is the snippet I currently use for URL rewriting in the root in my nginx server block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args
}
```

**Edit:**

This is what I previously had in .htaccess in the root:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and this in .htaccess in the admin folder:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /admin/index.php?strucutre_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If you would like advice on porting your `.htaccess` files to `nginx` then you should include the source in your question. Otherwise, the syntax of the `nginx` rewrite module is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Comment: @RichardSmith I added the relevant parts of the .htaccess files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the only thing missing from your implementation is special handling for the `/admin` location. I would suggest that you try this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
}
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?strucutre_url=$uri&$args;
}
```